# Using LINQ to join multiple MongoDB collections

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I have some trouble on how to join data in the following silly thought up example:

I have 3 collections:

```
Pets: [{
    "_id": ObjectId,
    "Name": string,
    "BodyParts": [{ "GroupId": ObjectId }]
}]

BodyParts: [{
    "_id": ObjectId,
    "PartName": string,
    "Colors": [{ "ColorId": ObjectId }]
}]

Colors: [{
    "_id": ObjectId,
    "ColorName": string
}]
```

It's very relational and Mongo may not be the best choice for this, but that's the situation I have.

I'd like to have a method where a Pet ID is provided and which returns a class something like this:

```
Pet GetPet(string petId)
{
    var data = _mongoCollection.FancyLINQ(petId);
    return new Pet(...);
}

class Pet
{
    string Id;
    string Name;
    List<BodyPart> BodyParts;
}

class BodyPart
{
    string Id;
    string PartName;
    List<Color> Colors;
}    

class Color
{
    string Id;
    string ColorName;
}
```

This could probably easily be done by sending 3 requests to Mongo and then assembling the data. One to find pet and it's list of body parts ids. A second to look up the parts and extract the colors. A thirds to look up the colors.

But that doesn't sound optimal. I can also use some native MongoDb syntax, but I'm not comfortable with this.

I'd prefer if this is possible using LINQ. I know joins can be done, but I haven't managed to find a way that solves my challenge above.

Bonus: if it can be constructed using LINQ, will it then, under the hood, call the database multiple times? Or only once, which I hope for.

I'm using the (at the time of writing) newest driver (2.17.1) and MongoDB version (6).

Comment: Why use a document style NoSQL database to store relational data?

Comment: That's unfortunately the situation I am in. I agree it would fit a relational database much better.

Comment: You'll need  three instances of `_mongoCollection`, each one connected to your desired collection.

Comment: Yes, but how do I write a (preferably) LINQ statement to join the data? I'd like to avoid having multiple calls if possible.

Comment: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/reference/driver/crud/linq/#lookup

Comment: The key is to use an aggregation pipeline on the pets collection with a $lookup stage to the bodyparts collection. The $lookup stage allows to specify another pipeline that is used when executing the lookup so you can specify a pipeline that looks up the colors with a $lookup stage from bodyparts to colors. I'd watch out for performance issues.

Comment: Another option would be to cache the data that are limited in the number of documents and change rarely (or never) e.g. the colors. This would eliminate the need to join these for every request. So you can create an aggregation pipeline on pets that looks up the bodyparts and add the colors later.

Comment: Yes, I'm also a bit concerned about performance as I'm not aware of how it actually processes a pipeline like that. 
I was told that MongoDb itself operates with data in memory and stores it occasionally. If that's the case, perhaps that could work as the cache mechanism? :)